# Create Banded Rows Using Pandas to_html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, win32com

I am attempting to create a styled HTML table from a dataframe to eventually be sent in an email using Win32. The dataframe that I am using might look something like this:

```
data_2 = [["Article 1", "Source 1", "Link 1", "Publication Date 1", "Keyword 1"],["Article 2", "Source 2", "Link 2", "Publication Date 2"]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns = ['Article','Source', 'Link', 'Date Published','Keyword'])
```

Using Pandas to_html function, I have added some styling methods with .replace()

```
html1 = df_2.to_html(border=0, index=False).replace('<th>','<th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid silver;">').replace('<td>','<td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">')
```

This results in the following HTML generation, which contains the actual results that this table might contain:

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid white;">Article</th>
      <th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid white;">Source</th>
      <th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid white;">Link</th>
      <th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid white;">Date Published</th>
      <th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:0px solid white;">Keyword</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">One Gas identifies 175 Bcf of renewable natural gas resources, lines up projects</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">S&amp;P Global</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">https://www.spglobal.com/marketintelligence/en/news-insights/latest-news-headlines/one-gas-identifies-175-bcf-of-renewable-natural-gas-resources-lines-up-projects-69101316</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">2022-02-25 18:00:04</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">ONE Gas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Sempra Energy (SRE) Q4 Earnings Beat, Revenues Rise Y/Y</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Nasdaq</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/sempra-energy-sre-q4-earnings-beat-revenues-rise-y-y</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">2022-02-25 16:09:00</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Dte Energy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Wayfair (W) Q4 Loss Wider Than Expected, Revenues Fall Y/Y</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Nasdaq</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/wayfair-w-q4-loss-wider-than-expected-revenues-fall-y-y</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">2022-02-25 15:20:00</td>
      <td style = "background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;">Cms Energy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to add banded rows to this table using the .replace() function? Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found the answer. For better or for worse, Outlook does not render nth child formatting. Via a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftFlow/comments/ju4e9a/html_table_formattingnthchild_not_working_in/) that I used:

"You are in a world of pain with styling emails with CSS especially when Outlook is involved. When in doubt assume that Outlook isn’t able to understand the syntax you throw at it. Nth child is much too modern and won’t work. Your only choice is to use inline styles - in general you do lots of inline styles in emails. It’s not pretty but it works."

Though this may not work in my case, the answer that I found was to replace the default to_html styling using the below:

```
html_2 = """<html>
<head>
<style>
table {  border-collapse: collapse;  width: 100%;}
th, td {  text-align: left;  padding: 8px;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #EDEDED; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #DBDBDB; color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid black; padding:1; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; padding:3;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0.5" class="dataframe">
  <thead>""" + df.to_html(index=False).replace('<th>','<th style = "background-color: #006666; color:white; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; border:.5px solid silver;">')
```

Which would, ideally, render something like this (but not in Outlook):

[image]